# Give the c++ code to given xml:

Tags: registry, get, attributes, msxml

i created an xml like registry structure.. i can node traverse through node name  ..here i cannot traverse a nodepath through **attribute value** ...i give the xml below..

```
 <Computer>
   <HIVE Name="HKEY_CUREENT_USER">
     <Elements>
       <element Name="(Default)" Type="REG_SZ" Data="(value not set)" /> 
       <element Name="SoftwareMicrosoftVisualStudio9.0ResourceEditorsPerformanceLoggingEnabled" Type="REG_SZ" Data="" /> 
     </Elements>
     <KEYS>
       <Key Name="Network">
         <Elements>
           <element Name="(Default)" Type="REG_SZ" Data="(value not set)" /> 
         </Elements>
       </Key>
     </KEYS>
   </HIVE>
 </Computer>
```

i want the path access"HKEY_CUREENT_USER\Network" ...give me a solution in c++
code(using MSXML)

Comment: Edit and make yourself clearer ... Your code does not appear ...

Comment: DO you mean you need a XML parser?

Comment: I downmodded -1 for the demanding "give me" attitude (which I happily will undo if the question is corrected). This post is lucky, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1259508/sample-c-program received a -5 reward.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Load into DOM and use following method:

```
IXMLDOMDocument::selectSingleNode(
     L"/HIVE[@Name='HKEY_CUREENT_USER']/Key[@Name='Network']/...")
```

Answer (score 1):

The XPath expression you need to access that is /Computer/HIVE/KEYS/Key[@Name='Network']

If you put this into a selectnodes statement on your DOM document then you will get a nodelist back, which you can interrogate for the information you require